# EXCEL_How to convert text into number

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function, vba

I'm working on a quality report and I've import the data into a sheet. But the numbers are all reserved as text, in seperated cells in one column.

```
                        | Average
colour | red   | red    | 
weight | 1.6   | 1.56   | 1.58
length | 1.1   | 1.12   | 1.11
type   | A     | A      | A
colour | green | green  | 
weight | 1.4   | 1.5    | 1.45
length | 10    | 9.6    | 9.8
type   | B     | B
```

And I'd like to culculate their averages for one row. You can leave `colour` and `type` aside, I've used `IF` function to judge if the test is these two then I'll do the other things with the result, and if the test is not (that means the result should be a number), I want to calculate the average.

But I'll meet the `DIV/0` error because of this problem. Sorry that I didn't find any code for formula or in VBA to finish this task, so if you've some idea, please leave a comment, thank you.

Comment: Did you try changing the format of the cells in excel sheet from text to number?

Comment: You can use `CInt` to convert your number stored as string, but in cases there is a string, you need also some error handling.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't work. The `number` is lying on the right of the cell, but `text` are on the left. And the cell of averages are still in Error.

Comment: Update your question with sample data in excel sheet.

Comment: @Hiddenllyy is the sample data you provided is in 2 columns ? or 1 ? what averages are you trying to calculate ? weight ? length ?

Comment: Assume first red is column B, second red is column C and row 2 contains the value 1.6 and column D contains averages then putting formula =AVERAGE(B2:C2) in D2 should give you the answer and then you can copy this in other cells.

Comment: ahh crap the example data changed!

Comment: Thanks @TheShooter But my problem is that `AVERAGE` doesn't work because the numbers are stored as `text`. So I'm looking for the way to change them into `number` and then do the calculate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your array A1:A10 has a mix of text and numbers stored as text. You can take the average of the numerical values as follows:

```
=AVERAGE(IFERROR(VALUE(A1:A10),""))
```

This is an array formula, so it will need to be entered using Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

Important: This will treat blank cells as zeros! If you want to ignore blanks, you can add in handling for that.

```
=AVERAGE(IFERROR(IF(ISBLANK(A1:A10),"",VALUE(A1:A10)),""))
```

Edit: In your example, it looks like you might want to be averaging specific rows. In this case, look into the `AVERAGEIF` function.

I also can't tell if your data is in one column or two. If it's in one, you'll first need to use Text to Columns with "|" as your delimiter to split it into two.

Comment: Thank you, it seems that your code should work but still the error becomes `value error`. And before, I just use `AVERAGE(A1:A10)` and when I change the numbers into `number`, it can calculate without error, but with your new formula it still doesn't work. It's really weird.

Comment: Are you sure you are seeing { } around your formula after you enter it?

Comment: Alright! I've found the mistake, thanks both of you!

Answer (score 2):

Following up on Alexis Olson comment on how you are averaging your numbers.  If this is just sample data and your real data is a combination of text and numbers, stick with Alexis Olson's answer.

If however you do want to average just the weight since averaging the weight and the length does not really make sense from a units perspective you may want to try:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$4:$B$11=E$4)*IFERROR(VALUE($C$4:$C$11),0))/COUNTIF($B$4:$B$11,E$4)
```

or

```
=SUM(($B$4:$B$11=E$4)*IFERROR(VALUE($C$4:$C$11),0))/COUNTIF($B$4:$B$11,E$4)
```

AVERAGEIF did not quite work because the third argument is asking for a range to average and we miss the opportunity to convert your text numbers to actual numbers.

Both of the above formulas are CSE or ARRAY formulas meaning you need to use <kbd>CONTROL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> when finishing the entry of your formula.  When done right {} brackets will appear around your formula in the formula bar.  Note that the {} cannot be added manually for the whole formula.

Proof of Concept

[image: POC]

---

## UPDATE#

**AFTER EXAMPLE DATA CHANGED**

```
=AVERAGE(VALUE(C9:D9))
```

This is a single cell array formula.  Place it in the first cell you want an average and be sure to use <kbd>CONTROL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>  when entering the formula and look for the { } around the formula after you have entered it  You can then drag the formula down or copy it into the individual cells where you want it

Proof of Concept II

[image: POC II]

Comment: Thank you so much for your patience, and sorry I've changed the example in the half way! I've tested your code and it works well but I still have to choose an answer and Mr.Alexis comes first so... Though thank you!! Have a good day:)

Answer (score 1):

> I'm looking for the way to change them into number and then do the calculate

To avoid the disadvantages of array formulae it would be much simpler to use either @Alexis Olson's or @Forward Ed's solution in non-array form but *after* selecting the range that contains green triangles and clicking on "Convert to number" 'in' the top left green triangle.

If green triangles aren't shown either turn on Error Checking (Options > Formulas) or insert `0` in a spare cell, copy that cell, select range to suit and Paste Special, Add.

Comment: after converting to numbers, just go with an averageif..if available

Comment: no just average is preferred, I was thinking back to the first set of example data we were presented with.  I did not know about the green triangle trick.  Glad you posted about that.